# Rolling Upgrades and Dynamic Software Update for JVM / Scala

Tags: scala, upgrade

I found some old articles on dynamic software update for Java:

Dynamic Software Updates for Java: A VM-Centric Approach (2008)  (See Citeseerx)

how to steal Erlang's hot code update for Scala/Java?:
http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/how-to-steal-Erlang-s-hot-code-update-for-Scala-Java-td1989938.html

On the Akka page there is a statement on that the Typesafe stack supports rolling upgrades:
http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/intro/why-akka.html
But I don't find any info on the Typesafe web.

K-Splice for Linux Kernel seems to be widely used for Linux.

I also found some note on that Tomcat supports replacing code but as I understand that seems to be for "stateless" code and not really applicable for other type of systems.

I assume OSGi bundles and similar systems could be used for replacing code on a modular level. But not really what I am after either.

What options are there for Scala and other JVM languages? Both in regards to DSU - Dynamic Software Update for single machine systems as well as for larger cluster / cloud deployed systems.

I find relatively bad information on this for the JVM compared to what exists for other languages like C/C++ but I would assume it should be simpler for JVM languages.

Something like Erlangs update system is what I think would be useful for Scala, but haven't found any such yet.

-Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'll want to be investigating [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) which is a standard for updatable modules within a running JVM.

Comment: In the question it is stated that OSGi bundles is not what I am after - yet you give an answer suggesting OSGi bundles...

Comment: I missed that to be honest, but you're asking for a feature and then dismissing pretty much the only thing that has that as one of its primary functions. Of all the languages, Scala is also the one that would probably be the least likely to work well with something that does this because of the complexities of the language and the functionality of the JVM it leverages.

Answer (score 1):

JRebel gets a lot of use - they provide a free license if you work with Scala:
http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/